# how can I change the color of road in google map api

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using two Google Maps APIs, and I'm trying to change the color of the roads because they're all black right now. Originally, the colors were normal, but once I search for a place and select it, the roads turn black. Is there a way I can change this?

btw
json part is working in only 'onMapReady' not in 'setOnPlaceSelectedListener' :(:(

json code =>
String styleJson = "[{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ff0000"}]}]";
mMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(styleJson));

`public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Geocoder geocoder;
private String API_KEY;

Button button;
MarkerOptions mOptions2 = new MarkerOptions();
LatLng selectedLatLng;
String selected_place = null;

// 지도에서 선택한 위경도
String selected_place_lat;
String selected_place_lon;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    API_KEY = "AIzaSyB6PEyWbF8b9vLc1BcwmLfHbfcLpJgo4xQ";
    // Initialize the Places SDK
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), API_KEY);
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment;

    autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));


    // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the selected place
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {

              //JSON
            String styleJson = "   [{\"featureType\":\"road\",\"elementType\":\"geometry\",\"stylers\":[{\"color\":\"#ff0000\"}]}]";
           // GoogleMap 
            googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(styleJson));



            selectedLatLng = place.getLatLng();
            mOptions2.title("Search Result");
            mOptions2.snippet(place.getName());
            mOptions2.position(selectedLatLng);
            mMap.addMarker(mOptions2);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(selectedLatLng, 15));

        }

    });


}


public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

  
    String styleJson = "[{\"featureType\":\"road\",\"elementType\":\"geometry\",\"stylers\":[{\"color\":\"#ff0000\"}]}]";
```

// GoogleMap 객체에 스타일을 적용합니다.
mMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(styleJson));

```
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
         
          //JSON
            String styleJson = "   [{\"featureType\":\"road\",\"elementType\":\"geometry\",\"stylers\":[{\"color\":\"#ff0000\"}]}]";
           // GoogleMap 
            googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(styleJson));
          
            MarkerOptions mOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            // 마커 타이틀
            mOptions.title("마커 좌표");
            Double latitude = latLng.latitude; // 위도
            Double longtitude = latLng.longitude; // 경도
            LatLng move = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);

            // 마커의 스니펫 (간단한 텍스트) 설정
            mOptions.snippet(latitude.toString() + ", " + longtitude.toString());
            // 위도 경도 쌍을 나타냄
            mOptions.position(new LatLng(latitude, longtitude));

            Log.d("Main activity 메인액티비티", "위도: " + latitude);
            Log.d("Main activity 메인액티비티", "경도: " + longtitude);

            // 마커 핀 추가
            googleMap.addMarker(mOptions);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(move, 15));


        }
    });

    LatLng SEOUL = new LatLng(37.556, 126.97);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(SEOUL);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SEOUL, 10));
}
```

`

I wanna see the gray colored road
when I search the place and select. not black